# How clock synchronization affects the performance of YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I would like to examine how the accuracy of clock synchronization affects the performance of YugabyteDB. How do you usually test such things internally?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, we use Jepsen tests to verify correctness, which introduces clock skew issues (as a part of a larger set of failures it introduces).
This report is old, but it explains the point: https://blog.yugabyte.com/yugabyte-db-1-2-passes-jepsen-testing/ (see “Pushing the boundary on tolerating clock skew”)

> YugabyteDB uses a combination of the monotonic and the HLC to make
> sure it is much more resilient to clock skew. Note that the
> —max_clock_skew_usec config flag controls the maximum clock skew
> allowed between any two nodes in the cluster and has a default value
> of 50ms. Kyle calls this out in his report (emphasis is mine in these
> quotes): YugabyteDB uses Raft, which ensures linearizability for all
> (write) operations which go through Raft’s log. For performance
> reasons, YugabyteDB reads return the local state from any Raft leader
> immediately, using leader leases to ensure safety. Using
> CLOCK_MONOTONIC for leases (instead of CLOCK_REALTIME) insulates
> YugabyteDB from some classes of clock error, such as leap seconds.
> Between shards, YugabyteDB uses a complex scheme involving Hybrid
> Logical Clocks (HLCs). Yugabyte couples those clocks to the Raft log,
> writing HLC timestamps to log entries, and using those timestamps to
> advance the HLC on new leaders. This technique eliminates several
> places where poorly synchronized clocks could allow consistency
> violations.